# WPF DataGrid Grouping: Grouping by 2 properties on one layer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I have a WPF DataGrid that groups by a property called customerID and a property called SiteID which works OK. However, I want to make it better so both properties are grouped on the same layer. i.e. when you drop down a group.

At the moment its grouping by CustomerID and then SiteID which is not what I want to happen.

is this possible to do?

Here is the grouping XAML thus far

```
     <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CustomerID "/>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="SiteID"/>
     </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have either `CustomerID` or `SiteID` set at one time. You could create a new property `GroupID` with a getter of `return CustomerID ?? SiteID;` and group on that.

Comment: Hi pavlindorm, so would I need to loop around the collection inside this new property and build the CustomerID and SiteID into some sort of array and then return?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a new property in the class containing `CustomerID` and `StoreID` named `GroupID` that returns the unique value you want to group by.

Comment: Oh I get you, so in the model of that class, create a new property called GroupID with the combing of CustomerID and SiteID

Comment: Exactly, though I wonder if simply combining them will not be only a different path to the same end. Combine in such a way as to simplify the identifier, not just concatenating the values.